# how can i change structure of the way i retrieve the data in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i  have this data set

| Family | Members | type of service 1 | Type of Service 2 | Type of service 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Family 1 | Member 1 | Cash | Education | Health |
| Family 1 | Member 2 | Education | work | cash |
| Family 2 | Member 1 | health | food | cash |

i want a query that makes the output like this structure:

| family | Member | Type of service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family 1 | Member 1 | Cash |
| Family 1 | Member 1 | Education |
| family 1 | Member 1 | health |
| Family 1 | Member 2 | Education |
| Family 1 | Member 2 | work |
| Family 1 | Member 2 | cash |

Comment: Why `Family 2` data is skipped in desired output?

Comment: no Forgot to keep it going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a union approach:

```sql
SELECT Family, Members, Service1 AS Service FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Family, Members, Service2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Family, Members, Service3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Family, Members, Service;
```